# Qt3D C++ How to shape outline?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

Does anyone know how to outline a shape in Qt3D using C++ (not QML).

For example using a cuboid mesh and make it transparent but outline the edges of the shape. Please see pictures attached on what I mean.

[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: Maybe, the [Wireframe QML Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html) provides what you're looking for. You stated that you're not interested in QML. Nevertheless, you can have a look into the used [shaders](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/examples/qt3d/wireframe/shaders?h=5.15) which are part of the sample code and may provide inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the outline of a shape, you can follow these steps:

1. Draw everything as normal.
2. Draw only the outline of the selected object.

When drawing the outline, you need to use an outline effect, which can be implemented in two render passes:

1. Render the geometry to a texture using a simple color shader.
2. Render to screen using a shader that takes each pixel in the texture and compares the surrounding pixels. If they are equal, we are inside the object and the fragment can be discarded. If they differ, we are on the edge of the object and we should draw the color.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I'm very new to Qt3D classes. I know how to create a basic 3D Scene with shapes and move them around but I don't know much about the rendering side.

Is there any examples or documentation that I can look at to achieve what you mentioned?

I had a look at Qt's docs but they aren't very detailed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).